# Google OAuth scope parameter to get user's first and last name

Tags: oauth

Does anybody know how to get the user's first and last name from google's oauth implementation?

I can get only the email address with the scope parameter https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email

but I can't find how to get first and last name...

anybody knows how to do that with oauth?

Comment: Which scope did you have to add to get first name and last name in the end?

Comment: since the name only comes as a single string of first and last name, one solution will be to use PHP to break the names into parts and use them as first and last names. ill write the code and post here when i do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a list of scopes you could include (separated by spaces) in an oauth initiation url, try http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#AuthScopes and try it out.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, documentation on the available scopes is nearly impossible to find. I am implementing `Oauth 2.0` which is still in the experimental stage with google's api. So, there's not nearly enough documentation.

It seems the scope needed for the name and profile picture is this:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

So you'll probably need to use:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#profile

By the way, you can make them both in one request

```
 someauthurl?response_type=code&client_id=123&redirect_url=someurl&scope=somescope1 somescope2 somescope3
```

Just separate them with a space.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the URLs you can try:

**Authentication**

```
NSString *scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
```

**Authorization**

```
NSString *urlAuthorization = @"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json";
```

Scope should get you the access token after you have signed in. Then you can use the urlAuth to get a nice JSON string of your profile info such as id, given_name (first name), family_name (last name), etc.

Also refer to http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/ in detail to see sample applications that can also help.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/#USERID# // like g+ profile id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Login with Google+, have a look at this:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people

Answer (score 0):

just include this "email%20profile" as the value of the scope e.g "**scope=email%20profile**" this will return the **email**, **first name** and **last name** of the user.

the complete url should look like this

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code&scope=email%20profile

replace CLIENT_ID and REDIRECT_URI with the correct values as obtained from [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/)